# Populate a select list from php oracle database

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to connect to Oracle database from the following PHP script to populate a drop down list but the script doesn't work.

Can anyone see an issue? Many thanks!

```
$conn = oci_connect('username', 'password', 'host');

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'select product_id, product_name from product order by product_id');
oci_execute($stid);

$query = "select product_id, product_name from product order by product_id";

$res = mysql_query($stid);
echo "<select name = 'Product'>";
while (($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) != null)
{
    echo "<option value = '{$row['product_id']}'";
    if ($selected_product_id == $row['product_id'])
        echo "selected = 'selected'";
    echo ">{$row['product_name']}</option>";
}
```

echo "";

Comment: "It doesn't work" - can you elaborate? What exactly is happening? Are you seeing an error, what output are you getting, etc?

Comment: If you do a `var_dump($row);` as the first line inside the while statement what does it show? What do your error logs say?

Comment: The issue is that the page is drawing the list box but no data is being inserted?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using mysql_* to interrogate an oracle database?? I think the right function to use is oci_execute

```
$res = mysql_query($stid);
```

The above line in your code is used to query a MySQL database,not Oracle.

Comment: I have tried to use that format but nothing is happening either way. The issue is that the page is drawing the list box but no data is being inserted?